# AWS Route 53 DNS alias for internal load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, internal-load-balancer

I've setup an internal load balancer for my SQL read servers in EC2, but I can't figure out how to point DNS at it.  I have a private hosted zone in Route 53.  When I attempt to setup an ALIAS record to the LB, the internal load balancer does not appear in the dropdown, though all the public LBs do, which leads me to believe I'm going about this the wrong way.  None of my Googling has led me to any information specific to private load balancers, so maybe it's just not possible and I have to use the long AWS domain name?

Comment: Your private LB still has a valid public name (example, `internal-name-123456789.region.elb.amazonaws.com`), but the DNS servers will resolve it to the corresponding private IP address.

Comment: If I try to set the target manually, Route 53 keeps adding "dualstack." to the beginning of the name.  Is this normal?

Comment: Yes do not worry about the dual stack AWS adds that because the application should support both both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: FWIW, [here's the AWS official documentation on Internal Load Balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-internal-load-balancers.html).

Comment: Yeah, it's just confusing because AWS provides autocomplete for public LBs, but not private LBs, leading me to believe I was doing something wrong.  Then when I tried manually, the "dualstack." led me to believe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I agree. It's somewhat confusing. Did you test to confirm it's working?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you!

Comment: How did you resolve this? I pointed the private DNS to the internal ELB (A record with Alias to ELB's DNS) but didnt work

Answer (score 2):

**My experience** : I was trying to create single HTTPS contact point for my application, so I tried setting up internal load-balancer hoping when I point it to A Record in Route 53 it would work with just A Record url.

**To answer your question :**

- Internal Load Balancers do list in Load Balancer listing for Route 53.
- You can not use A Record url to publicly point to internal load-balancer unless you are actually connected to VPC